What is the Cause, or why do people misquote Bible verses like 1 Timothy 6:10?
It strikes me recently just how many people will say that "Money is the root of all evil." when the actual Bible verse is... "A love of money is the root of all evil." I wonder why people say that and what is the cause of this most often misquoting of this Bible verse.
Not only do people "misquote" Bible verses, but often attribute sayings to the Bible that were never there, but found in only cultural folklore or perhaps used in some sermon or hymn of Christianity.
Why is there this tendency? What is the discernable cause for such a tendency?

This doesn't really seem like a Christianity question, as it's asking about how often people have misquoted the Bible. This might be better on Literature or something similar.

At its current state, the Q doesn't have a criteria for an objective answer, hence an invitation to opinion-based answers.  One way to remedy this is to ask the origin of the corruption from "A love of money is the root of all evil" into "Money is the root of all evil".

This is similar to how other quotes are used "out of context" in modern times. A great example is "The customer is always right" is not what was being said. "The customer is always right in matters of taste" is the full quote. So I would humbly suggest those who misquote it have an agenda that is not aligned with what God intends for your life. ||| This however is opinion and speculation. You need to rephrase your question Neil so it can be answered.

Post Christian Culture - This question speaks to the ignorance of Scripture and the superficial Christianity in this  post-modern world, and deserves our attention.

@ Neil Meyer - I adjusted your question to perhaps avoid "closure" of this important topic.  If dissatisfied, feel free to roll back.  Thanks for bringing up this topic! Peace.

Most Misquoted?Indeed this verse is often misquoted: The love of money is the root of all evil.  (Money is the root of all evil.) But whether it is the most misquoted is debatable. Especially if we include the most misused verse with it. Judge not lest you be judged. (Matthew 7:1) For in the following verses, Jesus advised looking at the fruit of men's lives to discern whether they are true or false men...whether they are men we should be wary of.
Post-modern SocietyHowever, this sloppy use of scripture is indicative of a greater social malady. Most modern, state-educated people are biblically illiterate. With the Bible being kicked out of public education in the 60s, most have no real understanding of the Bible or its scriptures. For example, some consider the "epistles to be the wives of the apostles."!!
There is also so much disinformation about the Bible bandied about by skeptic scholars in the institutions, and the students (and public) are none the wiser. The Bible's reliability, alleged outdated theology, patriarchy, etc. are all dissed.
Superficial ChristianityAnd those who claim to be Christian are often just cultural Christians, and not diligent adherents to enthusiastic worship on a weekly basis nor daily Bible reading (devotions). They feign a religiosity on the Holidays, but that's it.
So it is easy for them to misquote verses, or ascribe statements to the Bible that are not found there, but were introduced by men in their own works. For example, Cleanliness is next to godliness. or God helps those who help themselves. Or Charity is its own reward. Or Lazy hands (mind) are the devil's workshop.
Or The first profession was....
Founding Fathers of AmericaThe Founding Fathers of the Republic of America overwhelmingly recognized the importance of a Bible reading society. They realized that "it was impossible to enslave a Bible-reading people." They taught that the Holy Book was the foundation of American democracy (Andrew Jackson). And in order to establish a new government they read and quoted the books of the European philosophers (e.g. John Locke) whose books contained verse after verse of the Bible in them. The first Chief Justice of the Supreme Court also helped found the American Bible Society. President Thomas Jefferson, while Superintendent of Public Schools in Washington D.C., placed the Bible in all the schools (along with Watt's Hymnal.) Notice the biblical foundation of our tri-partied government:

For the LORD is our judge, the LORD is our lawgiver, the LORD is our King. (Isaiah 33:22)

[See Wallbuilders.com for extensive study of the biblical under-pining of America's founding.]
They would be appalled at the lax reading of the Bible in American homes... and the dissing of the Bible in modern society (educational institutions, judiciary, entertainment, liberal government).
Present DilemmaSo it can only be a portending of America's coming destruction---many would aver---with the Bible as a closed book. And it is a wonder that more misquoted verses aren't floating around society---and social media! But money is always a major concern in the modern mind, so this misquote in 1 Timothy is probably the one most abused.

Raise up your child in the way that he should go and when he is old he will not depart from it. There's a couple of generations here in America that, for the most part, have nothing to depart from. The problem has started in the home.  +1

This gets to the 'root' of the question by showing that 1 Timothy 6:10 is but one of myriad individual verses wrested out of context and miss-applied in today's sound-bite generation. There are so many misquoted verses, the whole lot of them ought to be collated and thrown into the rubbish-heap of church history. But I would add that what's coming does not have merely America in its sights. This is global.

Disrespect for the word of God and hostility against Christianity are on the increase. You are right to draw our attention to superficial and cultural Christianity and our biblically illiterate post-modern society.  Well said, sir!

As an old man, raised and educated in catholic schools (60's), active participant in the church (high school), brother of Third Order of Saint Francis, I can tell that bible education is barely better than no education at all. And I don't think that priests and pastors knows anything beyond their approved theology.

Yes, 1 Timothy 6:10 is often misquoted.

For the love of money is a root of all kinds of evil (NIV)

However, the Authorised (or King James) Version actually says:

For the love of money is the root of all evil...

Perhaps 1 Corinthians 10:13 could be a contender for failure to distinguish between suffering and temptation:

No temptation has siezed you except what is common to man... He will not let you be tempted beyond what you can bear... When you are [tempted] he will also provide a way out.

While I'm at it, I found a couple of very common expressions people think are in the Bible, but are not.

God helps those who help themselves

Not in the Bible but found in the words of a 1774 hymn by William Cowper.

Cleanliness is next to Godliness

Not in the Bible but found in a 1778 sermon by John Wesley.

Looking at the Greek of 1 Timothy 6:10, I can see both translations as valid options. The question is do you translate it as "a root" or "the root". And since it is easy to think of sins that are in fact not rooted in the love of money (adultery, murder, etc) then "a root" seems like the more appropriate translation within the context of scripture. And if it is "a root" then you can also communicate that same idea by downplaying the "of all evils" bit to give you the less literal but still accurate translation of "the root of many evils".

@RyanPierceWilliams Just to point out that love of money is often found to be at the root of many murders! Consider murders done to claim insurance policies! Or murders to enable drugs barrons to get rid of those who get in their way of massive profits! Also with adultery, that can also have an underlying desire to gain financial benefit. Once the extent of filthy lucre's influence is weighed up, it may be seen to be like the underground web of moss and mushrooms.

@Anne - yes, but (to be more explicit) my point is that other things like lust and anger serve as the root for sins as well. It is obviously false to state that greed / love of money is THE root of all evil; as if there were not other things that lead people to do evil.

@RyanPierceWilliams  Agreed, which is why "The love of money..." should always be quoted at the start! I think of the illustration of the (often) underground web of mycelium when it comes to seeing how sin exists. We see what appears as a result of that network, but the underground mesh is what gives life to its end product. Thanks.
